# EmberJS - Relationship not remotly pushed

Tags: ember.js

I have two model with a one to one relation. I only need one direction of the relationship.

```
App.A = DS.Model.extend({
    b: DS.belongsTo('b', { async: true }),
});

App.B = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Model A is load from the server.
Model B is manually pushed using `store.pushPayload`.

If Model B is loaded before Model A, everything is fine and `{{a.b.name}}` works correctly inside the template. But when Model A is loaded before Model B, then the name is empty (the whole relation is not set actually).

How can I tell model A that model B was loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember will automatically request your B model, if the relationship in model A exsists. Which ember/ember-data are you using? 
Are you using REST or JSONAPI adapters?

Your server response for model A needs to have the data about the relationship for model B.

i.e. in a JSON API response would look like this

```
"data": {
"type": "A",
"id": "1",
"attributes": {
  "some-attribute": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
},
"relationships": {
  "b": {
    "data": {
      "id": "123",
      "type": "b"
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no server interface for Model B. The data are pushed from another javascript part of the app to the store. I'm using EmberJS 2.5.0 and Data 2.5.1.

Comment: Then you need to manually set the relationship as well. So something like this `A.set('b', bObject)` after pushing bObject to the store.

Comment: I push to the object not the class right? so `a.set('b', bObject)`. Seams strange, if I push to the store, Ember should be able to handle the relation.

Comment: Well, ember will handle the relation, but you have to specify it. Either by pushing like this, or when creating the b object. But then you will need to have the reverse relationship in your b object as well. So you would need to have something like this: 
`App.B = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'), 
    a: DS.belongsTo('A'),
});`
And then pushing b to the store with the relationship specified as well:
`store.createreRecord('B', {'name': 'someName', 'a':ObjectA}`

Comment: Sorry for the delay igor. I now have a jsbin to illustrate what I mean. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/coqidayuhi/1/edit?html,js,console,output After 5sec the B models are appearing on the screen, so it works as expected. But if I use this URL: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/coqidayuhi/1 (basically just the view of the jsbin) it does not work! Within my app Ember also fails to solve relationships. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Looking at your example, if you change your model A belongsTo() relationship to `async: false` it will work. The thing it, async relationship is used when you expect ember to send a request out for your data (you might notice that you have 3 get requests with 404 responses), so it doesn't connect the relationships properly when you push the B model manualy. But if you dont use it async, then ember will expect you to provide the data, as you do already,  and it will connect the models.

Comment: Thanks Igo. I can't understand why I didn't test it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.